# encountered the symbol "INNER" when expecting one of the following ,;for group having intersect minus order start union where connect

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

I am using oracle form builder and created when-new-record-instance trigger on product data block that has:

```
select sum(s.Count) into :count.vt from u1.shopping_cart_items s
inner join u1.orders o on o.order_id = s.order_id
where s.product_id = :product.product_id and o.validated=1;
```

I get the following error:

> encountered the symbol "INNER" when expecting one of the following
>   ,;for group having intersect minus order start union where connect

what is this error means? how to solve it? thank you in advance.

Comment: Which version of Forms? Not sure if the latest version supports ANSI joins, but I'm sure some older - but relatively recent versions - did not. [This might be useful](https://sites.google.com/site/craigsoraclestuff/oracle-forms---how-to-s/forms-how-to---base-a-block-on-a-from-clause-query) (refers to this issue with Forms 10gR2 and triggers.) Or you could rewrite  with old-style joins... contrary to the advice often seen here to switch from old to new syntax *8-)

Comment: As @AlexPoole pointed out, still Forms( *I witness for 11g version* ) even doesn't support ANSI-92 syntax. If you persist using with the new style, try to store your SQL inside stored procedures/packages and invoke them from Forms.

Comment: Not really relevant to your question but the `inner` and `outer` keywords are optional and therefore, to me, annoying clutter. I always remove them when I get the chance.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that join is not supported by your version of Forms.

You can rewrite your query as following:

```
select sum(s.Count) into :count.vt
from u1.shopping_cart_items s, u1.orders o
where o.order_id = s.order_id
and s.product_id = :product.product_id
and o.validated=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

11g Forms definitely does not support ANSI standard join syntax.  I don't know yet if 12c Forms does.